# how to I deal with NaN results from FFT?

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to implement a function which takes an wav file, runs a 100th of a second worth of audio through the FFT by AForge. When I change the offset to alter where in the audio I am computing through the FFT, sometimes I will get results in which I can show in my graph but most of the time I get a complex array of NaN's. Why could this be?

Here is my code.

```
    public double[] test()
    {

        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.ShowDialog();
        WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(file.FileName);

        byte[] data = new byte[reader.Length];
        reader.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        samepleRate = reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        bitDepth = reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample;
        channels = reader.WaveFormat.Channels;

        Console.WriteLine("audio has " + channels + " channels, a sample rate of " + samepleRate + " and bitdepth of " + bitDepth + ".");


        float[] floats = new float[data.Length / sizeof(float)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, floats, 0, data.Length);

        size = 2048;

        int inputSamples = samepleRate / 100;
        int offset = samepleRate * 15 * channels;
        int y = 0;
        Complex[] complexData = new Complex[size];


        float[] window = CalcWindowFunction(inputSamples);
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSamples; i++)
        {

            complexData[y] = new Complex(floats[i * channels + offset] * window[i], 0);
            y++;
        }

        while (y < size)
        {
            complexData[y] = new Complex(0, 0);
            y++;
        }


        FourierTransform.FFT(complexData, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);


        double[] arr = new double[complexData.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < complexData.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = complexData[i].Magnitude;
        }

        Console.Write("complete, ");

        return arr;

    }

    private float[] CalcWindowFunction(int inputSamples)
    {
        float[] arr = new float[size];
        for(int i =0; i<size;i++){

         arr[i] = 1;   

        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Just throw them away, they are meaningless.

Comment: But all the results out of the FFT are Nan when this problem occurs, I need the real results.

Comment: @hotpaw2 If I scale all the input by say divide by a certain number will this a major affect on the audio if I was to convert back to time domain after (scaling back up by multiplying)

Answer (score 3):

A complex array of NaNs is usually the result of one (or more) of the inputs to the FFT being a NaN.  To debug, you might check all the values in the input array before the FFT to make sure they are within some valid range, given the audio input scaling.